# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshark'

Tags: python, pycharm, pyshark

I am getting this error message:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshark'
```

in Pycharm 2018.3 in Windows 8.1.
I have installed pyspark using `pip install pyshark` and `pip3 install pyshark`. But still, it is giving me the error

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshark'
```

What should I do now? What is the problem?

Comment: For installing `pyspark`, you have to do `pip install pyspark` not `pip install pyshark`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried a different IDE, python IDLE that comes with the installer, or just cmd/terminal itself?

Comment: By the way, as @Kishore said, are you trying to install `pyshark` or `pyspark` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was written by mistake. I have written pyshark